# How to write to console and log file simultaneously in PowerShell preserving CR LF

Tags: powershell, logging, newline

In a PowerShell script I want to write to the console and a log file simultaneously.

I did this:

```
Start-Transcript -Path $TargetDir\Log.log
Write-Host "Stuff"
```

which works great, except that the newlines it generates are `LF`, which means my logs look great in literally every text editor except Notepad.

That's what I did:

```
function global:Write-Notepad
(
    [string] $Message,
    [string] $ForegroundColor = 'Gray'
)
{
    Write-Host "$Message`r" -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor
}
```

which writes a `CR` to the end of every message, but it doesn't seem to write out lines like this.

```
&$ACommand | Write-Notepad
```

I'm not sure what syntax the piping operator expects, but I would greatly appreciate help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I settled on...

```
# This method adds a CR character before the newline that Write-Host generates.
# This is necesary, because notepad is the only text editor in the world that
# doesn't recognize LF newlines, but needs CR LF newlines.
function global:Write-Notepad
(
    [string] $Message,
    [string] $ForegroundColor = 'Gray'
)
{
    Process
    {
        if($_){ Write-Host "$_`r" }
    }
    End
    {
        if($Message){ Write-Host "$Message`r" -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
& $ACommand | Tee-Object -FilePath $TargetDir\Log.log | Write-Host
```

Tee-Object will send a copy of the pipeline objects to a file or a variable, and output at the same time.